# How does Flutter handle orientation change

Tags: flutter, dart, orientation

Is orientation change handling is as simple as widget's build is rerun with the updated dimensions in Flutter?

I ask because in Android, the whole Activity is rebuilt, which is why all the information is sent via intents.

Any gotchas to keep in mind while designing widgets so they will handle orientation changes or other changes that result in UI to change?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically - yes!  Now, more specifically the [`MediaQuery`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) widget listens for orientation/size/layout changes and rebuilds it's children. This widget is already a part of the `MaterialApp` and `WidgetsApp` widget so you probably don't need to include it.

If you want your widget to take advantage of the device orientation, you can use the `MediaQuery.of` static member to access a [`MediaQueryData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html), which contains the device orientation. For example, a simple widget which displays different text in portrait and landscape (needs to be the child of `MaterialApp`, `WidgetsApp`, or `MediaQuery`).

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    if (mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
      return const Text('landscape');
    }
    return const Text('portrait!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you to force the Flutter application to remain in Portrait (vertical) mode even if the user is rotating the SmartPhone

```
    void main(){
  ///
  /// Force the layout to Portrait mode
  /// 
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
  ]);

  runApp(new MyApp());
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question at all

Answer (score 2):

according to this [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation#2-use-an-orientationbuilder-to-change-the-number-of-columns) you can use `OrientationBuilder`.

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) 
         // return A
    else 
        // return B
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Jonah's answer above is right, for me personally, I would suggest using `switch` instead of `if`.

You need to implement different contents in related functions.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation) {
    case Orientation.landscape:
      return _landscapeContent();
    case Orientation.portrait:
    default:
      return _portraitContent();
  }
}
```

UPDATE

From the other side, when you have an internal boolean `_fullscreen` flag where you are keeping fullscreen state (let's imagine you have a fullscreen button somewhere and want to show that content even if the phone in the portrait mode), then `if` will be handier.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
  if (orientation == Orientation.landscape || _fullscreen) {
    return _landscapeContent();
  }
  return _portraitContent();
}
```